# Not able to install pytorch 1.2 with CUDA 9.2

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

I am trying to install the lastest version of pytorch with cuda enabled that is version pytorch v1.2 and cuda v9.2 which corresponds with my nvcc version (9.2) on a python 2.7 environment created using conda. (venv)

[image]

The command that I used was: `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch` 
which I was given as per my system configurations on the official pytorch website.

But then when I check on the python command line, my pytorch version still shows v0.4.1 and cuda v9.0.

[image]

Comment: Please insert text stuff as text, not images.

Comment: It's the output from my terminal

Comment: PyTorch just doesn't seem to support Python 2.7 on Windows. Can you switch to Python 3?